# terminal partitioning for each of subprocesses prints

Tags: python, terminal, subprocess, std, sys

Say we have multiple subprocesses like the following which has some results printed in real time to sys.stdout or sys.stderr.

```
proc1 = subprocess.Popen(['cmd1'],
                         env=venv1,
                         stdout=sys.stdout,
                         stderr=sys.stderr, 
                         )

proc2 = subprocess.Popen(['cmd2'],
                         env=venv2,
                         stdout=sys.stdout,
                         stderr=sys.stderr, 
                         )
```

However, after executing this script in the terminal, while looking at what is being printed, it is not easy to distinguish which print is from the first process and which is from the second.

Is there a solution for this to see the stdout of each process separately, like if the terminal screen could be partitioned and each partition would have shown the printing results from each process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have written for you a curses application which will do what you request: divide the terminal window into a number of partitions and then watch the different output streams in the different partitions.

The function `watch_fd_in_panes` will take a list of lists, where the sub-lists specify which file descriptors to watch inside each partition.

Here is what your example calling code will look like:

```
import subprocess
from watcher import watch_fds_in_panes

proc1 = subprocess.Popen('for i in `seq 30`; do date; sleep 1 ; done',
                         shell=True,
                         stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                         stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
                         )

# this process also writes something on stderr
proc2 = subprocess.Popen('ls -l /asdf; for i in `seq 20`; do echo $i; sleep 0.5; done',
                         shell=True,
                         stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                         stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
                         )

proc3 = subprocess.Popen(['echo', 'hello'],
                         stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                         stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
                         )

try:
    watch_fds_in_panes([[proc1.stdout.fileno(), proc1.stderr.fileno()],
                        [proc2.stdout.fileno(), proc2.stderr.fileno()],
                        [proc3.stdout.fileno(), proc3.stderr.fileno()]],
                       sleep_at_end=3.)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print("interrupted")
    proc1.kill()
    proc2.kill()
    proc3.kill()
```

To run it you will need these two files:

**`panes.py`**

```
import curses

class Panes:
    """
    curses-based app that divides the screen into a number of scrollable
    panes and lets the caller write text into them
    """

    def start(self, num_panes):
        "set up the panes and initialise the app"

        # curses init
        self.num = num_panes
        self.stdscr = curses.initscr()
        curses.noecho()
        curses.cbreak()

        # split the screen into number of panes stacked vertically,
        # drawing some horizontal separator lines
        scr_height, scr_width = self.stdscr.getmaxyx()
        div_ys = [scr_height * i // self.num for i in range(1, self.num)]
        for y in div_ys:
            self.stdscr.addstr(y, 0, '-' * scr_width)
        self.stdscr.refresh()

        # 'boundaries' contains y coords of separator lines including notional
        # separator lines above and below everything, and then the panes
        # occupy the spaces between these
        boundaries = [-1] + div_ys + [scr_height]
        self.panes = []
        for i in range(self.num):
            top = boundaries[i] + 1
            bottom = boundaries[i + 1] - 1
            height = bottom - top + 1
            width = scr_width
            # create a scrollable pad for this pane, of height at least
            # 'height' (could be more to retain some scrollback history)
            pad = curses.newpad(height, width)
            pad.scrollok(True)
            self.panes.append({'pad': pad,
                               'coords': [top, 0, bottom, width],
                               'height': height})

    def write(self, pane_num, text):
        "write text to the specified pane number (from 0 to num_panes-1)"

        pane = self.panes[pane_num]
        pad = pane['pad']
        y, x = pad.getyx()
        pad.addstr(y, x, text)
        y, x = pad.getyx()
        view_top = max(y - pane['height'], 0)
        pad.refresh(view_top, 0, *pane['coords'])

    def end(self):
        "restore the original terminal behaviour"

        curses.nocbreak()
        self.stdscr.keypad(0)
        curses.echo()
        curses.endwin()
```

and **`watcher.py`**

```
import os
import select
import time

from panes import Panes


def watch_fds_in_panes(fds_by_pane, sleep_at_end=0):
    """
    Use panes to watch output from a number of fds that are writing data.

    fds_by_pane contains a list of lists of fds to watch in each pane.
    """
    panes = Panes()
    npane = len(fds_by_pane)
    panes.start(npane)
    pane_num_for_fd = {}
    active_fds = []
    data_tmpl = {}
    for pane_num, pane_fds in enumerate(fds_by_pane):
        for fd in pane_fds:
            active_fds.append(fd)
            pane_num_for_fd[fd] = pane_num
            data_tmpl[fd] = bytes()
    try:
        while active_fds:
            all_data = data_tmpl.copy()
            timeout = None
            while True:
                fds_read, _, _ = select.select(active_fds, [], [], timeout)
                timeout = 0
                if fds_read:
                    for fd in fds_read:
                        data = os.read(fd, 1)
                        if data:
                            all_data[fd] += data
                        else:
                            active_fds.remove(fd)  # saw EOF
                else:
                    # no more data ready to read
                    break
            for fd, data in all_data.items():
                if data:
                    strng = data.decode('utf-8')
                    panes.write(pane_num_for_fd[fd], strng)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        panes.end()
        raise

    time.sleep(sleep_at_end)
    panes.end()
```

Finally, here is a screenshot of the above code in action:

[image]

In this example, we are monitoring both stdout and stderr of each process in the relevant partition.  In the screenshot, the line that proc2 wrote to stderr before the start of the loop (regarding `/asdf`) has appeared after the first line that proc2 wrote to stdout during the first iteration of the loop (i.e. the `1` which has since scrolled off the top of the partition), but this is cannot be controlled because they were written to different pipes.

Comment: seems very good, I am going to try it. Just a few questions: 1_Do you also know if it is dead-lock safe? because I read there can be possibility of a dead-lock when using subprocess readings. 2_Also do you think there might be a limitation for the number of processes we want to do this with

Comment: 3_My processes continue running while I see their stdout in the terminal in real-time and earlier when I had used communicate() or stdout.read() it would have remained stuck because the process hadn't terminated yet or had not given any error. Do you think there might be a problem with the above solution if this might be case?(I will know the answer though when I try it)

Comment: @Azerila I have modified the code (to avoid it wasting CPU), so please grab a fresh copy.  I will try to answer your questions in the next comment(s).

Comment: 1. I see no reason for it to deadlock. It is very conservative, and only reads one byte per file descriptor that `select` said was readable, before calling `select` again, so the `read` should not block. The `select` will sometimes block, but only when it is set to wait for output on _any_ file descriptor that has not yet seen an EOF, so the situation should not arise that the output from some process is not being read because the reader is blocking while waiting for output from a different process. (If the processes need any _input_, you will need a separate writer thread/process for that.)

Comment: 2. Regarding limitation on number, I think the practical limitation is how you manage the screen space. It will only split the screen vertically (with horizontal lines), not side-by-side. But you could reduce the number of partitions by grouping the output of _some_ processes into the same partition, while viewing others in different partitions, just by how you distribute the file descriptors among the sub-lists of the argument to `watch_fds_in_panes`. The example has each partition used for the stdout and stderr of one process, but this is entirely flexible.

Comment: 3. The watcher will terminate when it has received an EOF on all open file descriptors. Until then, it will keep watching for output (although if you press ctrl-C, it will exit gracefully). Once all the processes have terminated (or closed their stdout and stderr), the watcher should write any remaining data and then exit.

Comment: so it worked as expected, but there was one issue. when the process was printing something with color, the output in the terminal was not with that color and had included the color code, e.g.,  print('\33[34m' + 'simulators_root_node started' + '\x1b[0m'), would have also written the "\33[34m2 in the terminal rather than interpreting it as a color of the following string.

Comment: let me know if you had also a solution about the color issue when printing:)

Comment: @Azerila Sorry I don't know how you would write colours inside a curses pad. This is my first and only curses application! Try asking a new question.