# Running 2 processes at once and displaying the output from both of them in the same terminal

Tags: linux, bash

Is this possible?? If so how?

I would rather have 2 bash scripts running in one terminal instead of two.

They both need to be live output.

Comment: `./script1.sh & ./script2.sh &`? Though it means the output will be interleaved and they won't be interactive. It's not clear whether that meets your requirements as your description is not very detailed.

Comment: You know how terminator and stuff allows you to have multiple terminals?
Could you do something like that but just to run multiple scripts or functions at once on the terminal essentially splitting it?

Comment: There are utilities such as `screen` and `tmux` which may be what you want.

Comment: I have considered those but thats kinda besides my theoretical point if its just a new application.

Comment: Might be better worded to overlay some bash function over another?

Comment: Still unclear what you are asking about. What does "overlay" mean? You will have to be much clearer in describing your question if you hope to get an answer.

Comment: Hopefully this image will help explain what im trying to achieve. and to have both output live.
http://i.imgur.com/xCPBCgZ.png

Comment: Your theoretical point seems unnecessarily complicated: what if `script1` produces 1 line of output while `script2` produces 100 ... are you expecting the right or bottom half of your terminal to scroll while the other half does nothing? (If yes, then ... ***that*** is what `screen` and `tmux` are intended to do, and they do it *well*. Can somebody do for you what you're asking for? Sure, it would involve rewriting several components from those two utilities.)

Comment: Do you mean you want one process to scroll the top half of the screen and the other to scroll the bottom? Or one on the left and one on the right? Or lines from both scripts tagged with the script name and interleaved in the same area? Neither your description nor your diagram is very clear.

Comment: Here is a python script that I wrote previously for someone, which will do something similar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62106232/terminal-partitioning-for-each-of-subprocesses-prints . It could easily be adapted so that the commands which are run in each of the `subprocess.Popen` invocations shown in the example are passed on the command line.

Comment: Now added a command line interface - see answer.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is still unclear, but you can run two scripts or programs in parallel with **GNU Parallel** and tell it to tag each line of output with the name of the script that generated it and to interleave only on line breaks, i.e. not in the middle of a line, like this:

```
parallel --tag --line-buffer bash ::: script1.sh script2.sh
```

**Sample Output**

```
script1.sh  Result=0
script2.sh  Result=0
script2.sh  Result=1
script2.sh  Result=2
script2.sh  Result=3
script2.sh  Result=4
script1.sh  Result=1
script1.sh  Result=2
script1.sh  Result=3
script1.sh  Result=4
script1.sh  Result=5
script2.sh  Result=5
script1.sh  Result=6
script2.sh  Result=6
script1.sh  Result=7
script2.sh  Result=7
script1.sh  Result=8
script1.sh  Result=9
script2.sh  Result=8
script2.sh  Result=9
```

I used the following as a sample script, saving it as `script1.sh` and `script2.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash

for ((i=0;i<10;i++)) ; do
   echo Result=$i
   sleep $((RANDOM%4))
done
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this script:

https://gist.github.com/alaniwi/5203f96fc8ab86b327415df72d83bc7c

Example usage:

```
# example usage:
#
# this runs the following commands simultaneously, each in different areas of the screen:
#    1)   echo hello
#    2)   cal
#    3)   for i in 1 2 3 4 5 ; do date; sleep 1; done
# 
#  it waits for 2 seconds after they have all finished, before clearing the screen
#
./run_in_panes.py -s 2 'echo hello' 'cal' 'for i in 1 2 3 4 5 ; do date; sleep 1; done'
```

Gives:

[image]

Copy of the code here in case the gist becomes unavailable for any reason:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import argparse
import curses
import os
import select
import signal
import subprocess
import time


class Panes:
    """
    curses-based app that divides the screen into a number of scrollable
    panes and lets the caller write text into them
    """

    def start(self, num_panes):
        "set up the panes and initialise the app"

        # curses init
        self.num = num_panes
        self.stdscr = curses.initscr()
        curses.noecho()
        curses.cbreak()

        # split the screen into number of panes stacked vertically,
        # drawing some horizontal separator lines
        scr_height, scr_width = self.stdscr.getmaxyx()
        div_ys = [scr_height * i // self.num for i in range(1, self.num)]
        for y in div_ys:
            self.stdscr.addstr(y, 0, '-' * scr_width)
        self.stdscr.refresh()

        # 'boundaries' contains y coords of separator lines including notional
        # separator lines above and below everything, and then the panes
        # occupy the spaces between these
        boundaries = [-1] + div_ys + [scr_height]
        self.panes = []
        for i in range(self.num):
            top = boundaries[i] + 1
            bottom = boundaries[i + 1] - 1
            height = bottom - top + 1
            width = scr_width
            # create a scrollable pad for this pane, of height at least
            # 'height' (could be more to retain some scrollback history)
            pad = curses.newpad(height, width)
            pad.scrollok(True)
            self.panes.append({'pad': pad,
                               'coords': [top, 0, bottom, width],
                               'height': height})

    def write(self, pane_num, text):
        "write text to the specified pane number (from 0 to num_panes-1)"

        pane = self.panes[pane_num]
        pad = pane['pad']
        y, x = pad.getyx()
        pad.addstr(y, x, text)
        y, x = pad.getyx()
        view_top = max(y - pane['height'], 0)
        pad.refresh(view_top, 0, *pane['coords'])

    def end(self):
        "restore the original terminal behaviour"

        curses.nocbreak()
        self.stdscr.keypad(0)
        curses.echo()
        curses.endwin()



def watch_fds_in_panes(fds_by_pane, sleep_at_end=0):
    """
    Use panes to watch output from a number of fds that are writing data.
    fds_by_pane contains a list of lists of fds to watch in each pane.
    """
    panes = Panes()
    npane = len(fds_by_pane)
    panes.start(npane)
    pane_num_for_fd = {}
    active_fds = []
    data_tmpl = {}
    for pane_num, pane_fds in enumerate(fds_by_pane):
        for fd in pane_fds:
            active_fds.append(fd)
            pane_num_for_fd[fd] = pane_num
            data_tmpl[fd] = bytes()
    try:
        while active_fds:
            all_data = data_tmpl.copy()
            timeout = None
            while True:
                fds_read, _, _ = select.select(active_fds, [], [], timeout)
                timeout = 0
                if fds_read:
                    for fd in fds_read:
                        data = os.read(fd, 1)
                        if data:
                            all_data[fd] += data
                        else:
                            active_fds.remove(fd)  # saw EOF
                else:
                    # no more data ready to read
                    break
            for fd, data in all_data.items():
                if data:
                    strng = data.decode('utf-8')
                    panes.write(pane_num_for_fd[fd], strng)
        time.sleep(sleep_at_end)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        panes.end()
        raise

    panes.end()



def parse_args():

    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

    parser.add_argument("-s", "--sleep-at-end", type=float, metavar="seconds",
                        help="time to sleep for at end before clearing screen",
                        default=0.)

    parser.add_argument("commands", nargs="+", metavar="command",
                        help=("command to run in each pane "
                              "(if the command takes arguments, then quotation marks "
                              "will be needed around a command and its "
                              "arguments if invoking this from a shell)")
                        )

    return parser.parse_args()


def main():
    opts = parse_args()
    num_panes = len(opts.commands)

    procs = [subprocess.Popen(command,
                              shell=True,
                              stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                              stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
             for command in opts.commands]

    try:
        watch_fds_in_panes([[proc.stdout.fileno(), proc.stderr.fileno()]
                            for proc in procs],
                           sleep_at_end=opts.sleep_at_end)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("interrupted")
        for proc in procs:
            proc.send_signal(signal.SIGINT)
        time.sleep(1)
        for proc in procs:
            proc.send_signal(signal.SIGKILL)

            
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Thanks! Was looking for this for a long time

Answer (score 0):

As a cheap solution and nice-to-have-tool anyway, you could use [`multitail`](https://www.vanheusden.com/multitail/) for that.

```sh
# Terminal 1
./script1.sh > script1.output &
./script2.sh > script2.output &

multitail *output
```

I guess multitail would also have the option to read from STDIN or other file descriptors, but above example is probably the easiest usecase.

Going more fancy, `tmux` and/or `screen` (or the wrapper/config `byobu`) will do the job, but require some learning about their usage (well invested time, though).